# How to loop through input variables for a function in R?

Tags: r, function, loops, directory

I have a function, `biovars(prec,tmin,tmax)` with three variables as input. `prec,tmin,tmax` are multi bandGeoTiffs. However there are several Tiffs stored in different directories, that needed to be stacked before the can be passed to the function:

```
stack("/path1/to/file/prec1.tif") 
stack("/path2/to/file/tmin1.tif") 
stack("/path3/to/file/tmax1.tif")
```

How can I loop through each directory, stack the first file and use the result of the loop as input for the function:

```
biovars(prec1,tmin1,tmax1)
biovars(prec2,tmin2,tmax2)
...
biovars(precn,tminn,tmaxn)
```

Is there an easy way for doing this? I don't think it is possible with three for loops...

Comment: It is a GeoTiff with 12 bands

Comment: Based on your data, it looks like you only need one loop, because `prec`, `tmin` and `tmax` all use the same value from 1:n.  Feel free to correct me if this isn't the case. But in that case,
    `for (i in 1:n) {
        biovars(get(paste0(prec, i)), get(paste0(tmin, i)), get(paste0(tmax, i)))
    }`

Comment: What data type is that? CSV, TAB, XML? One column in each file?

Comment: @ Punintended: So it looks plausible. I did not know that this is possible. I'll try this. @ Parfait: The data type is  raster (GeoTiff)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description, I think you can do something like this:

```
library(dismo)
# setwd(root of data files")
fprec <- list.files(".", pattern="prec", recursive=TRUE, full.names=TRUE)
ftmin <- gsub("prec", "tmin", fprec)
ftmax <- gsub("prec", "tmax", fprec)
fbio <-  gsub("prec", "bio", fprec)   

for (i in 1:length(fprec)) {
   prec <- brick(fprec[i])
   tmin <- brick(ftmin[i])
   tmax <- brick(ftmax[i])
   b <- biovars(prec, tmin, tmax, filename=fbio[i])
```

}

Comment: Hi RobertH, your example worked for me. I had to adjust the input files a bit but the loop does the job! thx

Answer (score 0):

I always prefer to use `*apply` functions and avoid `get`. It also leads to easily read code (IMO).

```
prec_files = c("/path/prec1.tif", "/path/prec2.tif", ..., "/path/precn.tif")
tmin_files = c("/path/tmin1.tif", "/path/tmin2.tif", ..., "/path/tminn.tif")
tmax_files = c("/path/tmax1.tif", "/path/tmax2.tif", ..., "/path/tmaxn.tif")

prec_stacks <- lapply(prec_files, stack)
tmin_stacks <- lapply(tmin_files, stack)
tmax_stacks <- lapply(tmax_files, stack)

results <- mapply(FUN = biovar, prec_stacks, tmin_stacks, tmax_stacks)
```

If `biovars` returns a useful object, you can store the results of the `mapply` call.  If you hit memory limitations by (I assume) loading all the rasters at once, you can wrap the loading and `biovar` call into one function:

```
stack_and_biovar <- function(prec_path, tmin_path, tmax_path) {
  prec <- stack(prec_path)
  tmin <- stack(tmin_path)
  tmax <- stack(tmax_path)
  biovar(prec, tmin, tmax)
}


mapply(FUN = stack_and_biovar, prec_files, tmin_files, tmax_files)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly then there is a simple way to do it using either [`pmap` or `pwalk`](http://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/map2.html) from `purrr` package.

Basically, you list all the files with given patterns then use `pmap`/`pwalk` to loop through that list and pass corresponding file names to `raster::stack` and `biovars` functions.

```
    library(tidyverse)

    pathGIS <- "/path1/to/file/"
    filePattern <- list("^prec*", "^tmax*", "^tmin*")

    # List files and sort them numerically using mixedsort from gtools
    fileList <- map(filePattern, ~ gtools::mixedsort(list.files(path = pathGIS, recursive = TRUE,
                                                    pattern = .x, full.names = TRUE)))
    head(fileList)

    # ..1, ..2, etc. correspond to the sublist order within fileList
    pwalk(fileList, ~ biovars(raster::stack(..1), raster::stack(..2), raster::stack(..3)))
    pmap(fileList, ~ biovars(raster::stack(..1), raster::stack(..2), raster::stack(..3)))
```

Simple example

```
    fileList <- list(c("./GIS/prec1.tif", "./GIS/prec2.tif"), 
                     c("./GIS/tmax1.tif", "./GIS/tmax2.tif"), 
                     c("./GIS/tmin1.tif", "./GIS/tmin2.tif"))

    dummy_function <- function(precFile, tmaxFile, tminFile) {
      cat("\n-----\n")
      print(precFile)
      print(tmaxFile)
      print(tminFile)
      cat("-----\n")
    }

    pwalk(fileList, ~ dummy_function(..1, ..2, ..3))        

    -----
    [1] "./GIS/prec1.tif"
    [1] "./GIS/tmax1.tif"
    [1] "./GIS/tmin1.tif"
    -----

    -----
    [1] "./GIS/prec2.tif"
    [1] "./GIS/tmax2.tif"
    [1] "./GIS/tmin2.tif"
    -----
```